# Recognizing a cell input in one line

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions

Consider the following function where inputs are

```
>> b.a = 1    
b =     
    a: 1

>> c = {'this' 'cell'}    
c =     
    'this'    'cell'

>> d = [1 2 3]    
d =    
     1     2     3
```

The input can be called in many ways for example  `testfunction(b,d,c)` `testfunction(d,c,b)` etc I want to get the cell input and retrieve some data from it

```
function testfunction(varargin)
for i =1:numel(varargin)
    if(iscell(varargin{i}))
        fprintf('The input number %d is a cell!\n',i)
    end
end
```

which recognizes if a variable input is a cell but is there any elegant way to do it ? because `iscell` doesnt return back the index , I also used `class()` but it returns class of `varargin` instead of the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is not performance, but rather readability and having a pretty code.

I suggest you create a separate function that checks where the cell is, and call that function in your main function. This way you can check where the cell is, in a single line. It is simple, fast, and very easy to read. Since you can just save the function and close the script in the editor, it will be just like calling a builtin one-liner. The function can also do other input checks.

Example function:

```
function idx = cell_index(C)
idx = 0;
if isempty(C)
    warning('No input was given.')
else
    for ii = 1:numel(C)
        if(iscell(C{ii}))
            idx = ii;
        end
    end
end
if idx == 0
    warning('The input contained no cells.')        
end
end
```

Now you can do the following in your main function:

```
function output = main_function(varargin)
    idx = cell_index(varargin)
    fprintf('The input number %d is a cell!\n', idx)
    %
    % or fprintf('The input number %d is a cell!\n, cell_index(varargin))

% Rest of code
```

** Loops versus other approaches:**

Let's try out a few functions:

**Appraoach 1: Loop**

This is the fastest one:

```
function s = testfunction1(varargin)    
for ii = 1:numel(varargin)
    if(iscell(varargin{ii}))
        s = sprintf('The input %i is a cell!\n', ii);
    end
end
end
```

**Approach 2: cellfun**

This is slowest and hardest to read (IMO):

```
function s = testfunction2(varargin)    
if any(cellfun(@(x) iscell(x),varargin))
    s = sprintf('The input %s is a cell\n', num2str(find(cellfun(@(x) iscell(x),varargin))));
end    
end
```

**Approach 3: cellfun**

This is the easiest one, assuming you don't want loops

```
function s = testfunction3(varargin)    
x = find(cellfun(@(x) iscell(x),varargin));
if ~isempty(x)
    s = sprintf('The input %i is a cell \n',x);
end    
end
```

The following benchmarking is performed using Matlab R2014b, prior to the new JIT engine!

```
f = @() testfunction1(b,c,d);
g = @() testfunction2(b,c,d);
h = @() testfunction3(b,c,d);
timeit(f)
ans =
   5.1292e-05

timeit(g)
ans =
   2.0464e-04

timeit(h)
ans =
   9.7879e-05
```

---

**Summary:**

If you want to use a loop-free approach, I suggest the last approach (the second `cellfun` version). This performs only one `find` and one call to `cellfun`. It's therefore easier to read, and it's faster.

Comment: Griffen : Hi, I will gladly accept your answer but I was already aware of the `cellfun` which is also a wrapper function for a for-loop  I just wanted to know if there is a way we can get index from a function just like `ismember` , maybe I wasnt able to explain my question properly

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the loop avoiding in this case, but this should do the trick .

```
testfunction(b,c,d) 
testfunction(b,c,d,c)
testfunction(b,d)


function testfunction(varargin)

if any(cellfun(@(x) iscell(x),varargin))
fprintf(['The input(s) ' num2str(find(cellfun(@(x) iscell(x),varargin))) ' is (are) cell \n']);
end

end
```

Comment: cellfun is wrapper function for a for loop :) anyways +1

Comment: well yes, but it is 'Recognizing a cell input in one line' :). But i get your point and i will try again. Are there always exactly 3 inputs?

Comment: no number of inputs can be even 100 but one of them is a cell